# How to show a calculated field result while filling out the form before submitting

Tags: sharepoint-online

How can I display a calculated field result from a SharePoint field to a SharePoint new form which is customized by infopath. Let's say I inter time in and time out and the total calculated hour should be available before I save the form. Currently I can only see the result after I save and close the form on edit form and view form.

Enter sign in time= 7am

Enter sign out time= 9am

Hours worked= 2

I wanna see the hours worked after I enter the time.currently I can see the hours worked total after I save the form and open the edit or display form

Thanks !

Comment: To show a calculated field result based on sign in time field and sign out time field before saving the form, you could create rules in InfoPath form to calculate the two fields. 
Then before submitting, the calculate result of the two fields will display in the hours worked field.
For more detailed information, refer to the article below.
https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/infopath/2007/02/21/calculating-elapsed-timewithout-code/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After a lot of searching I managed to figure out subtracting date and time field came from SharePoint list. the steps I took was as follows…

1. Create two date and time fields and take the value from Time In and Time Out fields and parsed the date stamp from them
2. Change the format in to military time 24H format.
3. Create another filed for today’s Total Time and use the below formula on XPath

translate(xdDate:AddSeconds(../my:EndTime, -1 * (substring(../my:StartTime, 1, 2) * 3600 + substring(../my:StartTime, 4, 2) * 60 + substring(../my:StartTime, 7, 2))), "ER?", "")

You can see the formula at the following link
http://www.braintrove.com/id/95